# How to preserve \n on front-end when fetching data from firebase database?

Tags: vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch the data from Firebase Realtime database with \n preserved on front-end.

With css property: "white-space: pre-line", I'm able to send \n to firebase database, but when I'm trying to fetch the data on front-end using Vue.js it's not maintaining the \n.

Firebase database is an array so, I tried to convert the array to the string and it converts "\n" to the white space. I didn't find any online help how to preserve \n while displaying data on front-end

My firebase database:

```
answers
 0: "some data"
 1: "some data. more data.\nsomething"
```

I'm using for loop to display each answer to new line. But splits each key-value to new line not data with "\n".

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database doesn't do anything with the newlines in your text.  Everything in a string is taken exactly as you specify.  It's likely that you're doing something wrong, but without seeing any code, it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the `\n` with `<br/>` and display your it as html.

```js
let str = "some data. more data.\nsomething";

str = str.replace('\n', '<br/>');
// "some data. more data.<br/>something"
```

And then display it using the `v-html` directive.

```html
<span v-html="str"></span>
```

This will display your content as html.

However : dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities. Only use HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided content.

See here :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Example :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    answers: ["some data", "some data. more data.\nsomething"]
  },
  computed: {
    transformed_answers() {
      return this.answers.map(a => a.replace('\n', '<br/>'));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="answer in transformed_answers">
    <p v-html="answer"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. map() actually helps.

Comment: I'm using your method mention in Example section. But thing is I'm using two arrays, questions and answers. I'm using `v-for` loop over questions array and combing corresponding answer with `:key`. With your method how can I use the `key` to correspond each question with answer?